# Xml documewntation for Asp.Net.Core webapi with Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, openapi

Im using asp net core 3.1 web api. I want to include xml documentation to swagger ui.

Im using de following methods in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddOpenApiDocument(...)
```

and there in Configure:

```
 app.UseOpenApi();
 app.UseSwaggerUi3();
```

Im a bit confused, cuz many developer using AddSwaggerGen and UseSwagger, and then use IncludeXmlComments() extension method.

Questions:

Is there a way to include xml comments in asp net core 3.1 with the built in libraries?

If yes what is the proper way to include Xml comments?

Should i install Swashbuckle.AspNetCore?

Comment: Are you using NSwag? if you are you should read: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/XML-Documentation

Comment: Yes.. I found out that, in request method the xml comment ll appear properly. Controller comments not show at all with class end enum comments. But i can add DesriptionAttribute to visualize some data in classes. Idk what am doing wrong. Its just feels like im missing something. I would prefer the only xml comments way.

Comment: `Controller comments not show at all` maybe that is the way it works... Are you using NSwag?

Comment: With the amount of code you provided it will be impossible for anyone to help out... Can you provide a minimum, reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code to you .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I found the answer on the microsoft site here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments